# Android app crash : Map size does not match number of entries(android.os.BadParcelableException)

Tags: android

My Android app is crashing with a 'BadParcelableException' exception at onSaveInstanceState when trying to save a HashMap using putSerializable. I am using the following code to save the HashMap in onSaveInstanceState of BaseActivity:

```kotlin
private var appSettingsMap = HashMap<String, String?>()

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putSerializable("app_settings", appSettingsMap)
}
```

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       
    savedInstanceState?.let { inState ->
        val appSettingsMap =
            inState.getSerializable("app_settings") as HashMap<String, String?>?
        appSettingsMap?.let {
            if (it != appSettingsMap) {
                appSettingsMap = it
            }
        }
          
    }
}
```

This is causing the following crash report:

```
Fatal Exception: android.os.BadParcelableException: Map size does not match number of entries!
       at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:962)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeMap(Parcel.java:939)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1811)
       at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:989)
       at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1640)
       at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
       at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4750)
       at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:257)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8185)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
```

How can I fix this issue?